# can't join table on request

Tags: sql

I'm having issues on table joins in a sql query. I've looked it up on SO but nothing matched my problem.

Here are the two tables:

```
Charge 
| tache_id (int) | semaine_id (int) | login (varchar) | charge (float) |

Tache 
| tache_id (int) | type_id (int) | charge (float) |
```

Basically, every task (Tache) has a charge attribute which represents the amount of work (in days) necessary to complete the task.
The user can then plan it on several weeks (Charge).

**What I want to do is display all the tasks that haven't been completely planned, and then display (in an other window) those who are.**

I thought of doing something like this:

```
select Tache.tache_id, Tache.charge
left join Charge on Charge.tache_id = Tache.tache_id
where sum(Charge.charge) < Tache.charge
group by Tache.tache_id
```

But I get a 'invalid use of group function' error

Comment: DId you forget the FROM maybe? SELECT ... FROM ...

Comment: Tag dbms product used. (Some of them have a very strange GROUP BY behavior...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something on these lines, if tache.tache_id is unique:

```
select Tache.tache_id, max(Tache.charge)
from  tache
left join Charge on Charge.tache_id = Tache.tache_id
group by Tache.tache_id
having sum(Charge.charge) < max(Tache.charge)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you meant is a having clause, you can use aggregate functions in the where clause..

```
select Tache.tache_id, max(Tache.charge)
from  Tache
left join Charge on Charge.tache_id = Tache.tache_id
group by Tache.tache_id
having sum(Charge.charge) < max(Tache.charge)
```